# PHP pages showing up as Not Found

Tags: php, apache

Im not sure what m doing wrong here but the server cant seem too find my php files hosted on the server. Not sure if this is due to Apache lacking something or php itself. Ive searched all over the internet followed everything I can find and am having no luck.

http://netauto.app.local/data.php thats the file im trying to reach.

```
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  6493 Jul 26 23:47  action_search.php - call this 
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root   640 Jul 26 23:48  data.php - call this 
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root    20 Jul 29 21:53  info.php - call this 
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 15272 Jul  2 18:43  __init__.py
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 12964 Jul  2 18:43  __init__.pyc
drwxrwxrwx 2 root root  4096 Jun 18 16:37  __pycache__
drwxrwxrwx 3 root root  4096 Jul 27 01:46  static
drwxrwxrwx 4 root root  4096 Jul 26 22:48  templates
drwxrwxrwx 6 root root  4096 Apr 10 16:32  venv
```

Ive elevated everything to root with chmod 777 I want to change that to 644 but was running out of ideas. All the ones marked "call this" return a 404 not found when I try and navigate too it via the url. Also a debug on the website returns a 404 not found when I hit the php action.

folder paths look like this

```
---------flaskapp.wsgi
-----------------/FlaskApp
---------------------__init__.py
----------------------data.php
----------------------action_search.php
----------------------info.php
----------------------/templetes
----------------------/static
```

Heres the php mod

> root@pdc-mgmt-netutl:/var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp# php -v
>   PHP 7.2.19-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 (cli) (built: Jun  4 2019 14:48:12) ( NTS )
>   Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
>   Zend Engine v3.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
>       with Zend OPcache v7.2.19-0ubuntu0.18.04.1, Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by Zend Technologies
>   root@pdc-mgmt-netutl:/var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp# cd /etc/apache2/sites-available/

Below is my flask.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/FlaskApp/flaskapp.wsgi
        WSGIDaemonProcess FlaskApp python-home=/var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/venv/
        WSGIProcessGroup FlaskApp
        ServerName localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/
        <Directory /var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                Require all granted
                allow from all
        </Directory>
        Alias /static /var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/static
        <Directory /var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/static/>
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
                Require all granted
        </Directory>
        Alias /templetes /var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/templetes
        <Directory /var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/templetes/>
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
                Require all granted
        </Directory>
        LoadModule php7_module modules/php7apache2_4.dll
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
        # alert, emerg.
        LogLevel warn
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
        <IfModule dir_module>
                DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
        </IfModule>
        AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
        AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php
        PHPIniDir "/etc/php/7.2/apache2/php.ini"
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: A quick fyi.  Your directory listing shows a folder named templates but your configuration mis-spells it as templetes.  Also your ServerName is localhost but you're trying to call it via an FQDN of netauto.app.local.  Apache's default folder for content is usually /var/www/html from memory.  Have you tried moving the content in there to begin with?

Comment: hey thanks for the info, i migrated info.hp too html folder and still not calling it. I did change it from localhost too fqdn still no change. I i added the below too my host file on the server "127.0.0.1       netauto.tech.local". Let me change the templates good catch hope thats it. Just fixed the misspelling still no love. Reset apache / reset the server.

Comment: Have you looked at /var/log/apache2/error.log?  Perhaps write a small index.php (in /var/www/html) as follows and see if it works:
    <?php phpinfo(); ?>
i.e. browse to it via http://localhost/index.php

Comment: yea its not giving me any indication I have a problem or at least i dont think.   [Tue Jul 30 21:23:21.059497 2019] [core:notice] [pid 18188] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'. I have tried the info.php its still not loading just tried in in /var/www/html

Comment: How about creating a small static file like index.htm in /var/www/html with just <html><head></head><body>HELLO</body></html> in it.  Try to browse to http://localhost/index.htm

Comment: same thing not found made a static test.html file and placed it in the /var/www/html path

Comment: When I try to go to that page, or even your main site -- it's not resolving.  Which means you have a DNS issue.

Comment: This site isn't hosted externally